# Program works on GCC 7.5 on PC but not on online compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have the following program that compiles successfully on my machine using GCC 7.5.0 but when i try out the program [here](https://onlinegdb.com/BbIN3Gp1S) the program doesn't work.

```
class Foo 
{
    friend void ::error() { }

};
int main()
{
    
    return 0;
}
```

The error [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/BbIN3Gp1S) says:

```
Compilation failed due to following error(s).

    3 |     friend void ::error() { }
      |                         ^
```

My question what is the problem here and how can i solve it.

Comment: This seems to be a bug on GCC 7.5.0. You should remove the body `{ }` of the friend function `error` and make it a declaration by adding semicolon `;`.

Comment: Or remove the scoping operator `::`.

Comment: Please also post the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that a **qualified** friend declaration cannot be a **definition**. In your example, since the name `error` is qualified(because it has `::`) so the corresponding friend declaration cannot be a definition.

This seems to be a bug in GCC 7.5.0. For example, for gcc 7.5.0 the program [works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FBfqSX8OUyxc54wd) but for gcc 8.4.0 and higher it [doesn't work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fxOEmMa1QoBOmJaF).

One way to solve thiswould be to remove the body `{ }` of the `error` function and make it a **declaration** by adding semicolon `;` as shown below:

```
//forward declare function error()
void error();

class Foo 
{
    friend void ::error();//removed the body { } . This is now a declaration and not a definition

};
int main()
{
    
    return 0;
}
//definition of function error 
void error()
{
    
}
```

Note you can also put the definition of function `error()` before the definition of class `Foo` as shown [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/P1zxOO5AnuCmytx2).

Another way to solve this would be to remove the `::` and make `error` an **unqualified name** as shown [here](https://onlinegdb.com/AsWHVRWMN)